# python Parsing html page: how to decode � char?

Tags: python, parsing, utf-8

I'm trying to parse an HTML page like this

```
# coding: utf8
[...]
def search(self, a, b):
    word = self.champ_rech_canal.get_text()
    url_canal = "http://www.canalplus.fr/pid3330-c-recherche.html?rechercherSite=" + mot_canal
    try:
       f = urllib.urlopen(url_canal)
       self.feuille_canal = f.read()
       f.close()
    except: 
       self.champ_rech_canal.set_text("La recherche a échoué")
       pass
    print self.feuille_canal
```

The result is good, also I have � as "é" or "ô"
How can I decode it?
Tried:

```
self.feuille_canal = self.feuille_canal.decode("utf-8")
```

Result:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8789: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to decode an ISO-8859-1 page as UTF-8, which cannot work. See the content header in the returned HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, there's this line in HTML code. Can I try to replace it?

Comment: Just use your decode with `"iso-8859-1"`. The encoding of the text won't change magically if you change the text.

Comment: Yes, Matthias is correct, you have to decode with the encoding given by the site.